# How to download file from docker linux container to client file system by file name?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I have asp net core app in Docker Linux container. When I download file from file server my app downloads file from file server to docker container, but I want to download it to client file system. Can I do that, if I can how can do that using asp net core 3.1?

Answer (score 2):

well ,use bind-mounts and sync it together:

[image]

```
docker run -d \
   --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/dockertest/,target=/var/www/madeup \
   nginx
```

forCopy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
see docker cp --help

```
docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with asp net, but here is my logical thought after working on many web applications.

**Could you simply just transfer the file from server to client via HTTP?**

Maybe you could have a route that handles the download request from your client (you might have to send along a UUID or something to determine which file you are requesting), and then simply send the file data back over with the response?